# What is POST endpoint?

Tags: post, adobe, aem

I was testing on my aem test site, where everything seemed fine but I got an endpoint - site.com/content/dam.json and the response body is:

```
{"jcr:primaryType":"sling:OrderedFolder","jcr:mixinTypes":["mix:lockable","rep:AccessControllable"],"jcr:createdBy":"admin","jcr:created":"Fri Jan 20 2017 12:42:20 GMT-0500","cq:conf":"/conf/global"}
```

When I make a POST request the response is content changed successful,

Being unauthenticated is it really possible to POST any script, page, or anything on the application using this endpoint?

If so how?
Help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: As far asI know, you have to create a session first before you can make modifications in crx. For creating a session you need an user who has writing rights on your target node.

Comment: was the request made in publish or author?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you were testing authenticated (more likely as the admin user), that is the reason your POST are able to modify the content. Unless you give permission to the anonymous user (which is bad practice), your public facing sites are safe.